# Mat-input on focus is not working Angular7

Tags: angular

I have a requirement to a form with radio buttons and input box like this.
[image]

input box otherPaymentAmount is required.I have added `(focus)` as event to check wheather the value is empty or null then blur review button.
But its not happening anything I am missing over here?

Instead I end up with review button enable when I focus on input box.

[image]

### component.ts

```
createDefaultForm() {
    this.scheduleForm = this._formBuilder.group({
      paymentAmount: [null],
      otherPaymentAmount: [null, Validators.required]
    });
  }


onBlur($event) {
      if (this.scheduleForm.controls.otherPaymentAmount.value === '' || this.scheduleForm.controls.otherPaymentAmount.value === null) {
        this.scheduleForm.controls.otherPaymentAmount.setErrors({'OTHER_AMT_REQUIRED': true});
      }
```

### template.html

```
<div class="choose-payment-amount">Choose Payment Amount:</div>
        <mat-radio-group class="radio-group"  formControlName="paymentAmount" aria-label="choose payment amount">
          <mat-radio-button>
                 Minimum Payment Due> : {{scheduleForm.controls.toAccount.value.minPaymentDue | currency}}
          </mat-radio-button>
          <mat-radio-button>
                Statement Balance> :{{scheduleForm.controls.toAccount.value.lastStatementBalance | currency}}
          </mat-radio-button>
          <mat-radio-button>
                  Current Balance :{{scheduleForm.controls.toAccount.value.balance | currency}}
          </mat-radio-button>
          <mat-radio-button value="other">$
            <mat-form-field  [style.width.rem]="50">
            <mat-label>Other Amount</mat-label>
              <input required matInput  (focus)="onBlur()"
                     (click)="this.scheduleForm.controls.paymentAmount.setValue('other');"  formControlName="otherPaymentAmount">
              <mat-error *ngIf="scheduleForm.controls.otherPaymentAmount.invalid">
                {{errorMsgService.getAmountErrMsg(scheduleForm.controls.otherPaymentAmount)}}
              </mat-error>
             </mat-form-field>
          </mat-radio-button>
        </mat-radio-group>
      </div>

<div class="nav-btns">
        <button mat-button type="button" class="mat-button mat-raised-button" [disabled]="scheduleForm.errors || scheduleForm.invalid || scheduleForm.pristine " (click)="setDataToReview()"
                aria-label="REVIEW">REVIEW</button>
        <a class="cancel-link" aria-label="CANCEL">CANCEL</a>
      </div>
```

Comment: the value of paymentAmmount if you select the last button is "other" not null because you has `<mat-radio-button value="other">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can also has only one control if you use a [(ngModel)] to get the value of input and put as [value] the value of the variable. Well. You need add a (input) and update the value, and updateAnd validity. Well, in code, the last option can be like

```
  <mat-radio-button class="example-radio-button" [value]="another">
    <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
    <input matInput [(ngModel)]="another"
    [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" 
    (input)="scheduleForm.get('paymentAmount').setValue(another);
             scheduleForm.get('paymentAmount').updateValueAndValidity();
             scheduleForm.get('paymentAmount').markAsDirty()">
    </mat-form-field>
  </mat-radio-button>
```

See a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yv7yj3?file=app%2Fradio-ng-model-example.html)

Comment: Thanks by the way I am using reactive forms and Angular 7 so not preferred to use [(ngModel)]

Comment: The [(ngModel)] it's only to create the las option. The form is a Reactive Form